# Inserting NULLs to a float datatype column in sql using python

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains some missing values(Nans). I am trying to insert the dataframe into the database using `fast_to_sql in python`. The table has columns with datatype **float** and I am **not able** to **insert Nans in the database**.
I tried converting Nans to None becuase None = Null in db:

```
df = df.replace({np.nan: None})
```

but still "None" is object type and not float, so insertion to sql db fails due to type mismatch.

How to insert in the right way? Is there a best practice?